# Harmony ES6 constructor types for Map vs Object?

Tags: dictionary, v8, ecmascript-harmony

How come when I create a Map it requires `new` and it is not required on an Object?

```
var o = new Object();
var m = new Map();

var constructorObject = o.constructor;
var constructorMap = m.constructor;

var newObject = constructorObject();
var newMap = constructorMap();  //splat
```

That last line produces,

```
TypeError: Constructor Map requires 'new'
    at Map (native)
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply depends on the implementation of the `Map` feature. You get this error in Chrome, while in Nightly calling `Map();` returns you a beautiful brand new Map.

Keep in mind that the fact that you can create objects without using the `new` operator is just more or less useless (one could argue that it serves a purpose for the `Object` constructor as it doesn't simply return a new object, but an object which type matches the type of argument you passed). You could do the same for any constructor:

```
function Test() {
  if(!(this instanceof Test)) return new Test;
}
Test(); // equivalent to *new Test;*
```